# Sample from a Normal-Inverse-Chi-Squared distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, python

Is there a way to draw samples from the following distribution in Python?
[image: distribution]

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find helpful information in the scipy help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall10/sta114/notes15.pdf) document, on page 2, if $Z \sim$ Normal Inverse $\chi^2$ distribution$(m,k,r,s)$, then $Z = (W,V)$ such that
$$\dfrac{rs}{V} \sim \chi^2_r \quad \text{and} \quad W|(V = v) \sim N\left(m, vk^{-1} \right).$$

Thus to sample from a Normal-Inverse $\chi^2$ distribution, you sample $V$ first and then sample $W$. For your parameters you have, $Z \sim$ N-Inv-$\chi^2$$(\beta, \sigma^2\Omega^{-1}; v_0, s_0^2).$

Thus, you first sample $V = v$ such that,
$$\dfrac{v_0 s_0^2}{V} \sim \chi^2_{v_0}. $$

This can be done by first sample an $x$ from $\chi^2_{v_0}$ and then set $v = v_0s_0^2/x$.

Next, using this $v$, you want to sample $W = w$ such that,
$$W|(V = v) \sim N(\beta_0, v\sigma^{-2}\Omega). $$

Thus the draw $(w,v)$ will be a draw from the N-Inv $\chi^2$.

(I am not familiar with Python, but I am sure there are functions that will help you draw from a $\chi^2$ and Normal distributions.)